# APDU response read Binary to Objective-C String

Tags: ios, nsstring, hex, byte, smartcard

```
unsigned char get_cplc_command2[] = {0x00, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03};
receive_length = sizeof(receive_buffer);

ret = SCardTransmit(card,
                    &sendPCI,
                    get_cplc_command2,
                    sizeof(get_cplc_command2),
                    NULL,
                    receive_buffer,
                    &receive_length);

LOG(@"SCardTransmit 0x%08x", ret);

if (ret == SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD)
{
    goto retry;
}
else if (ret != SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
{
    [err_text setString:@"SCardTransmit failed on CPLC (w/ Le > 0)"];
    goto cleanup;
}


// GET RESPONSE
unsigned char get_cplc_command3[] = {0x00, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12};
receive_length = sizeof(receive_buffer);

ret = SCardTransmit(card,
                    &sendPCI,
                    get_cplc_command3,
                    sizeof(get_cplc_command3),
                    NULL,
                    receive_buffer,
                    &receive_length);

LOG(@"SCardTransmit 0x%08x", ret);


if (ret == SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD)
{
    goto retry;
}
else if (ret != SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
{
    [err_text setString:@"SCardTransmit failed on CPLC (w/ Le > 0)"];
    goto cleanup;
}

NSMutableString* cplc = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

if (receive_buffer[receive_length-2] == 0x90 && 
    receive_buffer[receive_length-1] == 0x00)
{

    unsigned char* p = receive_buffer + 3;        



    NSUInteger size = sizeof(p);

    NSMutableString *mutString =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(int i=0;i<=size-1;i++)
    {
        [mutString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X",p[i]]];
    }

    NSString * str = mutString; //@"8510000002030100043DC000C0000000006A9000";
    NSMutableString *newString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < [str length])
    {
        NSString * hexChar = [str substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
        int value = 0;
        sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
        [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
        i+=2;
    }

}
```

I am trying to read Smart Card,have got success response after GET RESPONSE command. trying to read receive_buffer data and convert to NSString.  But I am getting junk String "=AAj" for newString.  Please help me how to read receive_buffer.

Comment: Please add more information about error(s) you get.

Comment: I am trying convert Hexadecimal response received from receive_buffer to NSString so that I can get data from Smart Card.  But after converting Hexadecimal value to NSString it shows as characters like "=AAj", not able to read data from Smart Card.

Comment: Smart cards typically reply with very strange data containing NUL characters, control characters and others. So I'm not convinced, that what you receive is garbage. As soon as you represent it in hexadecimal, it should comply with the SELECT response of ISO 7816-4.